# GridGain: inheritance in the SQL query

Tags: gridgain

Is it possible to perform queries using parent class in GridGain?
Let say I have **Person** class and it's descendant **CustomPerson**. If I put both type of objects in the same cache will I be able to run a query like

`GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<Long, Party>> qry = queries.createSqlQuery(Person.class, "from Person");`

expecting all the objects in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for GridGain they are just two different classes and thus put into two different SQL tables.

I'd suggest to use UNION ALL query like

```
select _val from Person where age = ?
union all
select _val from CustomPerson where age = ?
```

Comment: Thank you, Bobby. Quite inconvenient thing((( In case a lot of applications use Person extensions you are not able to  count all the person (or do common analytics) objects inside some administration application if you're not aware of all the extensions.

Comment: For your use case it is but a lot of applications need exactly opposite behavior from what you suggested. I believe it is pretty easy to abstract away such an inconvenience with query generator in your application.